# How to use Git tags with semantic versioning in mix.exs?

Tags: git, elixir, elixir-mix, semantic-versioning

### Background

We have a private repository in `git` that uses tags. In our `mix.exs` we have the following:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      { :plug,    "~> 1.0"  },
      { :my_repo, git: "git@github.com:my_company/my_repo.git", tag: "1.0.0"  }
    ]
  end
```

Now if I only want version `1.0.0` from `:my_repo` that's fine. 
However what happens if I want any version compatible with 1.0.0? The original documentation doesn't seem to have an options flag for this:

https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html

### Problem

This is what is happening in `{ :plug, "~> 1.0"  },`. Here I say  "*give any 1.X version compatible with this one*".

I want the same thing for git repos. After checking the git docs, I know this is possible using the `-l` command:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

`git tag -l "1.8.5*"` would return all versions compatible with 1.8.5.

### Questions

1. Is there a way to pass the `-l` option to the mix.exs `deps` function?
2. If not, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass the `-l` option to the `mix.exs` deps function?

Not that I am aware of.

> If not, what other options do I have?

I would either propose a PR to `mix` core or just introduce your own `Mix.SCM` implementation, along with [existing `git` and `path`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/tree/master/lib/mix/lib/mix/scm), that would be an exact copy-paste from [`Mix.SCM.Git`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/595171d2cf4ee9104d7ed1b0ee4453b02dfefb40/lib/mix/lib/mix/scm/git.ex#L124) but allowing / hardcoding `-l` option.